# React Native: Bizarre and sporadic :"TypeError: Network request failed" errors

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, ios-simulator

After booting up my react native project, certain requests to my api were getting "TypeError: Network request failed" errors...  didn't seem like there was any rhyme or reason to it.  I hadn't run into any issues prior.  Quitting and rebooting the simulator didn't solve the issue.

*SOLUTION*:
While quitting and rebooting the simulator didn't work, resetting the "Content and Settings" (in the top menu bar under "Simulator") did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

While quitting and rebooting the simulator didn't work, resetting the "Content and Settings" (in the top menu bar under "Simulator") did the trick.